# Log into the iOS YouTube app (iOS 4.2.1) OR Export favorites some other way?

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I am upgrading an iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1) to an iPhone 5c (iOS 7). Unfortunately, the iPhone 3G's YouTube app (the old Apple-made app) was never logged into a YouTube account, and now seems not so be able to authenticate, so I can export the app-only list of video Favorites.

So, my question is, is there any way I can currently log in to YouTube with this app, or save that, export a list of favorites?

I have searched, and found in several places the suggestion that two-factor authentication be enabled on the Google account, and create an application-specific password to log in with the old YouTube app. However, we tried this method, and it did not work in our case. The old Apple-written YouTube app rejects this password combo.

Answer (score 1):

open youtube on computer log in copy link and mail to a friend  open mail on iphone  go to sent open the one you mailed open link. then on bottom of screen hit foward button then save to screen   new app my youtube

Comment: It took me a few reads through your answer to figure out what you meant, since there's no punctuation. I suppose that would have worked, but I was looking for a batch solution, instead of something that would require me to transfer over a hundred links one-by-one.